# Error while using INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY, using a for loop array

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am working on updating a mysql database using pyspark framework, and running on AWS Glue services.

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df2= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("xxx1","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("xxx2","81A01","TERR NAME 55","NY"),("x103","81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ")], ["zip_code","territory_code","territory_name","state"])

# Print out information about this data
df2.show()
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|zip_code|territory_code|territory_name|state|
+--------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|    xxx1|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
|    xxx2|         81A01|  TERR NAME 55|   NY|
|    x103|         81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|
+---------------------------------------------
```

I have a primary key ZIP_CODE, and I need to ensure, there is no duplicate keys, or primary key exceptions, and hence am using INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEYS.

And since I have more than one rows to insert/update, I have used for array in python to loop through the records, and perform INSERT into database.  The code is as follows:

```
sarry = df2.collect()
for r in sarry:
     db = MySQLdb.connect("xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com", "username", "password", 
      "databasename")
     cursor = db.cursor()
     insertQry=INSERT INTO ZIP_TERR(zip_code, territory_code, territory_name, 
     state) VALUES(r.zip_code, r.territory_code, r.territory_name, r.state) ON 
     DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE territory_name = VALUES(territory_name), state = 
     VALUES(state);"
     n=cursor.execute(insertQry)
     db.commit()
     db.close()
```

When running the above insert query function, I am getting the following error message, couldn't get any clue on the error.  Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2291407229037300959.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2291407229037300959.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 893, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1103, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1396, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1059, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 384, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'r.zip_code' in 'field list'")
```

If i simply try to print the values for one row, am getting the values printed as follows:

```
print('zip_code_new: ', r.zip_code, r.territory_code, r.territory_name, r.state)

zip_code_new:  xxx1 81A01 TERR NAME 55 NY
```

Thanks.  I am working on AWS Glue/Pyspark, so I need to use native python libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following insert query works, with a for loop.

```
insertQry="INSERT INTO ZIP_TERR(zip_code, territory_code, territory_name, state) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE territory_name = %s, state = %s;

n=cursor.execute(insertQry, (r.zip_code, r.territory_code, r.territory_name, r.state, r.territory_name, r.state))
print (" CURSOR status :", n)
```

Result output:

```
CURSOR status : 2
```

Thanks.  Hope this will be of reference to others.

Comment: hi yuva, 
the for loop appears as a way to sequentially update each row into MySQL. 
if so, it will likely lead to problems when handling with large real-time batches of data. how do you handle the same?

Comment: I had changed the logic, used LOADDATA FROM S3 PREFIX, provided by RDS Aurora to load data into a STAGING table, and then insert...on duplicate.. into target table from the staging table.  Hope this helps.

Comment: hi yuva, can help provide the answer to what was the final query you used?
would certainly be helpful! :)

Comment: Please refer to this SO post where i have provide sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621916/automate-bulk-loading-of-data-from-s3-to-aurora-mysql-rds-instance/55682730#55682730.  Let me know if you need any help. You may need to upload pymysql connector as part of your pyspark glue code, a zip file.