# Automate bulk loading of data from s3 to Aurora MySQL RDS instance

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am relatively new to AWS so I am not sure how to go about doing this,

I have CSV files on s3 and I have already set up the Aurora instance on RDS. The thing that I am unable to figure out is how do I automate the bulk loading of data, essentially doing like a `LOAD DATA FROM s3` kind of thing using something like AWS Glue.

I also used the Glue native thing of s3 to RDS, but then it is essentially a bunch of inserts into RDS over a JDBC connection which is also super slow for large datasets.

I can do it independently running the command on RDS but I do not want to do that and want to leverage Glue. I also looked at using a MySQL connector for Python but Glue natively only supports Python 2.7 which is something that I do not want to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does loading the data directly from S3 to Aurora not work for your requirements? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html

Comment: That is what exactly works but I am not sure how do I go about automating the whole thing, like running the Glue job to do the ETL and then loading the transformed CSV into RDS. How do I go about doing the whole thing together in an automated way?

Comment: Consider adding an S3 trigger on uploads to the bucket. Use that to invoke a lambda function that then loads the data to RDS.

Comment: But doesn't Lambda have like a 300 sec limit for the whole function to be run? Also, I am not sure how to write a Lambda, are there examples of it anywhere?

Comment: Lambdas can run for 15 minutes. There many examples in the AWS docs. We don't know how much data you are moving, how frequently, or any of your requirements, so it's hard to suggest architectures. Why do you not want to use the MySQL connector?

Comment: It's about a gig worth of data on a daily basis. Also, which MySQL connector are you talking about, the one which Glue provides or the Python ones? I have seen the Python ones but AWS natively supports only Python 2.7 through the Glue service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach is as stated above, have an S3 event trigger and a lambda job listening on the s3 bucket/object location.  As soon as a file is uploaded to the s3 location, the lambda job will run, and in the lambda, you can configure to call an AWS Glue job.  This is exactly we have done and has gone successfully live.  Lambda has a 15minute life, and it should take less an a minute to trigger/start a Glue job.

Please find herewith a sample source for reference.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import boto3
import time
import urllib

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
glue = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gluejobname="your-glue-job-name here"

    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist '
              'and your bucket is in the same region as this '
              'function.'.format(source_bucket, source_bucket))
    raise e
```

For creating a Lambda function, go to AWS Lambdra->Create a new function from Scratch->Select S3 for event, and then configure the S3 bucket locations, prefixes as required.  Then copy paste the above code sample, inline code area, and configure the glue job name as needed.  Please ensure you have all required IAM roles/access setup.

The glue job should have provision to connect to your Aurora, and then you can use "LOAD FROM S3....." command provided by Aurora.  Make sure all parameter group settings/configurations are done as needed.

Let me know if any issues.

**UPDATE: SAMPLE code snippet for LOAD FROM S3:**

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=url, user=uname, password=pwd, database=dbase)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur, conn = connect()
createStgTable1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydb.STG_TABLE;"
createStgTable2 = "CREATE TABLE mydb.STG_TABLE(COL1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, COL2 VARCHAR(50), COL3 VARCHAR(50), COL4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL);"
loadQry = "LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://<bucketname>/folder' REPLACE INTO TABLE mydb.STG_TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4) SET col1= @var1, col2= @var2, col3= @var3, col4=@var4;"
cur.execute(createStgTable1)
cur.execute(createStgTable2)
cur.execute(loadQry)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I already took care of the lambda function. Where do I write the `LOAD DATA FROM s3` statement, does it go within the lambda code?

Comment: Manas, it should be in the Glue job, since lambda has a time limit. Having the "load data from s3...." in AWS Glue makes it better assuming there would be large volume of data, some point of time.  Moreover Lambda is not ideal for an ETL rather can be used as orchestration service to trigger the AWS Glue.

Comment: I tried that with the Glue job, but the MySQL connector part of the code that you uploaded above is giving me issues in terms of using an external library in Glue job. From what I am seeing is that I can only use Python 2.7 libraries with Glue and that was part of the question that I asked above. Really appreciate all your help with this.

Comment: yes, you need to use pymysql library as a zip file, and add to the glue job.

Comment: Oh okay! That was kind of what I was doing... Nevertheless, thank you so much for all the help!!! I guess this is the way to go then...

Comment: Glad it was useful, and i was of some help. Thanks.  We use the same logic and they are in production successfully.