# Glue job is taking time to read parquet files one by one in a loop and writing it to a aurora DB

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timeout, query-optimization, aws-glue

I have S3 folder which has multiple records :

`s3://bucket/app-events/year=201909`

This folder has multiple parquet file and based on watermark file which contains:

```
{"last_modified_time": "2021-09-01 00:00:00", "end_time": "2022-09-02 23:59:59"}
```

This decides from which day and time the files should start reading. We are reading file one by one in a loop and writing it simultaneously, which is taking time in case of huge data . Is there any technique to merge the record when we are reading record one by one .

Comment: Your question requires more detail in order to understand it clearly. But one suggestion that I can give is first read all the files in an dataframe array and then do union on all the elements of the dataframe array to get the final dataframe and then write the final dataframe only once. this would save you some time and it would be more performant.

Comment: you may try "Load from S3.." feature for Aurora, load the data into a staging table and then insert from the staging table into target table using a where clause to filter based on last modified_time & end_time.  You may need to make some chgs to parameter group, and IAM roles.  pls refer for my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621916/automate-bulk-loading-of-data-from-s3-to-aurora-mysql-rds-instance and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html