# Using Python to Import Multiple CSV Data into Microsoft SQL from S3 Browser

Tags: python, amazon-s3

How to use python to bulk import the multiple `.csv` and folder into MySQL from S3 Browser?

Previously, using python to import multiple `.csv` to Microsoft SQL from own desktop folder. However, it taken longer time for completing the import process.

Had try solution stated in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682730/19403948 (MySQL) but failed.

Can anyone assist on this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide some details on why the solution in the linked answer is failing or example code you were using

Comment: MySQL and Microsoft SQL is different module? I am using Microsoft SQL and the solution stated is MySQL.

Comment: Then the issue is not the python code but the SQL query you are using for bulk import. You could use `sqlalchemy` for connecting and [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method if you want to solve it in python. Otherwise you need an alternative SQL query. I'm not familiar with the Microsoft SQL dialect, but this looks promising: [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)