# Spark jdbc overwrite mode not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I would like to perform update and insert operation using spark
please find the image reference of existing table

[image: existing table]

Here i am updating id :101 location and inserttime and inserting 2 more records:

[image]

and writing to the target with mode overwrite

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .option("url",  "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test")
  .option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("dbtable","temptgtUpdate")
  .option("user", "root")
  .option("password", "root")
  .option("truncate","true")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save()
```

After executing the above command my data is corrupted  which is inserted into db table

[image]

Data in the dataframe

[image]

Could you please let me know your observations and solutions

Answer (score 3):

Spark JDBC writer supports following modes:

- append: Append contents of this :class:DataFrame to existing data.
- overwrite: Overwrite existing data.
- ignore: Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.
- error (default case): Throw an exception if data already exists
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Since you are using "overwrite" mode it recreate your table as per then column length, if you want your own table definition create table first and use "append" mode

Comment: i would like you check the first image there i already have a table with data i want to update records in the table

Comment: is it possible you can share dummy df in your question to recreate issue , if data already in table should be update

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to perform update and insert operation using spark

There is no equivalent in to SQL `UPDATE` statement with Spark SQL. Nor is there an equivalent of the SQL `DELETE WHERE` statement with Spark SQL. Instead, you will have to delete the rows requiring update outside of Spark, then write the Spark dataframe containing the new and updated records to the table using `append` mode (in order to preserve the remaining existing rows in the table).

Comment: Then what's the functionality of  option truncate and mode overwrite  .

Comment: I have clarified my answer around SQL Delete. For the Spark JDBC write modes you should refer to the documentation.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a 'truncate' option in the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframewriter#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.

Answer (score 1):

In case where you need to perform UPSERT / DELETE operations in your pyspark code, i suggest you to use pymysql libary, and execute your upsert/delete operations.  Please check this post for more info, and code sample for reference : [Error while using INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY, using a for loop array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920803/error-while-using-insert-into-table-on-duplicate-key-using-a-for-loop-array)

Please modify the code sample as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was also investigating how can we achieve data load without dropping the table. So, there are only two options in hand:

1. Use "overwrite" option and let spark drop and recreate the table.
2. Use "overwrite" with "truncate" option to let spark just delete existing data and load.

I was able to achieve the 2nd one which is much better due to the fact that the table definition is not altered. I am not sure who would want the first option.

Like so - dataframe.write.option("overwrite", "true").option("truncate", "true").jdbc(...)

Answer (score -1):

Upsert logic is working fine when following below steps

```
  df = (spark.read.format("csv").
        load("file:///C:/Users/test/Desktop/temp1/temp1.csv", header=True,
             delimiter=','))
```

and doing this

```
  (df.write.format("jdbc").
    option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test").
    option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").
    option("dbtable", "temptgtUpdate").
    option("user", "root").
    option("password", "root").
    option("truncate", "true").
    mode("overwrite").save())
```

Still, I am unable to understand the logic why its failing when i am writing using the data frame directly

Comment: This just has the effect of truncating the table and inserting the rows from the dataframe. There is no update behaviour here.

Comment: dbtable need dbname.tbname

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend TRUNCATE, since it would actually drop the table, and create new table.  While doing this, the table may lose column level attributes that were set earlier...so be careful while using TRUNCATE, and be sure, if it's ok for dropping the table/recreate the table.

Comment: It's actually the other way around, the `"truncate"` option avoids dropping the table. Here's the reference from the documentation:
>  "This is a JDBC writer related option. When SaveMode.Overwrite is enabled, this option causes Spark to truncate an existing table instead of dropping and recreating it. This can be more efficient, and prevents the table metadata (e.g., indices) from being removed."
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html