How to insert and update rows in PostGreSQL table from Spark Dataframe
I am writing streaming data into a PostgreSQL table using Spark streaming every minute. I want to inserted or update records for each ID, where ID is the primary key, into Postgres table I tried using "Append," but it appends records instead of updating existing IDs. I also tried using "Overwrite," but it overwrites the entire table each time.
*For example I have New Dataframe and Table data below *
Dataframe



ID
Value




1
11


3
33



Table



ID
Value




1
10


2
22



I need to write new DataFrame into PostgreSQL table and expected output would be:



ID
Value




1
11


2
22


3
33




For UPSERT, you need to have your own merge logic, or INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY...() like in Mysql.  Please refer this for sample code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920803/error-while-using-insert-into-table-on-duplicate-key-using-a-for-loop-array/50941287#50941287
